# applying a function to a subset of columns in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with *many* columns. I would like to group by `id` and `transform` a subset of those columns leaving the rest untouched. What is the optimal way to do this? In particular, I have a df with a bunch of id's and I would like to z-score columns `a` and `b` within each id. Column `c` should remain untouched. In my actual problem I have many more columns.

The best I can think of is passing a `dict` of `{col_name: function_name}` to `transform`. For some reason this raises a `TypeError`.

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123) #reproducible ex
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"a": np.arange(10), "b": np.arange(10)[::-1], "c": np.random.choice(a = np.arange(10), size = 10)}, index = pd.Index(data = np.random.choice(a = [1,2,3], size = 10), name = "id"))

#create a dict for all columns other than "c" and the function to do the transform
fmap = {k: lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std() for k in df.columns if k != "c"}
df.groupby("id").transform(fmap) #yields error that "dict" is unhashable
```

Turns out this is a known bug: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17309

Comment: A little confused here. What is your end goal and what is your expected output here?

Comment: the expected output here is just to add 1 to columns a and b, and return c without modification (again, i realize the groupby is not necessary for this operation but in my use case it is necessary)

Comment: Your problem has been hyper generalised, so any possible answer is likely not going to work for your actual data. I could post an answer but I guarantee you and I are going to go through an hour long back and forth to fix the answer for your data. Cut us both some slack and narrow down your problem a bit.

Comment: For example, I can tell you right now that `df.groupby('id')[df.columns[df.columns != 'c']].transform(lambda x: x + 1)` works here but is not going to work for your data. How do I know that? Call it a badger's intuition. The problem is, we don't know what will, and what won't be directly applicable to your problem, so answering it won't be straightforward.

Comment: sure, happy to: what do you think i can improve in the question to make it more specific? 

wrt your second comment, i addressed that by saying i have very many columns so listing them in this way isn't super practical. it would also be helpful to know why my method fails.

Comment: A minimal example that more closely mimics your actual problem would be great. What are the conditions? What is the transformation? What will the data look like?

Comment: As to why your method fails: transform doesn't accept dictionaries. Simple as that. `agg` does. But it doesn't look like you're performing groupwise aggregation here, which is the most concerning thing about your question - it makes it seem like groupby is useless, and trying to "imagine" how it would be useful for your actual problem is not possible because your actual problem is not clear...

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html

this says it does accept dictionaries unless the groupby object has a very different transform function.

edited the example to be more specific

Comment: That's a different function.

Comment: In actuality, how many column will you select? How will you select them? Based on what condition?

Comment: There are 1,113 columns. I will select 805. The condition is simply based on names I read from a file.

Comment: Use `df.filter` and specify a regex. Again, I can't answer more concretely since I don't know the naming pattern you have.

Comment: do you have the link for the groupby.transform docs? can't seem to find the correct spec of the function

Comment: 1. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation -- actually useful, and 2. https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html -- completely useless

Comment: ok, thank you. read through 1 but that's pretty vague about what you can specify in transform. was hoping there would be something like the link i posted for the dataframe.transform. will take a look at using df.filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is filter columns names first by `difference`, because `dict` cannot working with `transfrom` yet:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['c'])
print (cols)
Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')

fmap = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
df[cols] = df.groupby("id")[cols].transform(fmap) 
print (df)
           a         b  c
id                       
3  -1.000000  1.000000  2
2  -1.091089  1.091089  2
1  -1.134975  1.134975  6
3   0.000000  0.000000  1
1  -0.529655  0.529655  3
2   0.218218 -0.218218  9
3   1.000000 -1.000000  6
2   0.872872 -0.872872  1
1   0.680985 -0.680985  0
1   0.983645 -0.983645  1
```

Comment: i like this solution a lot! thanks! didn't realize you could subset groupby object columns in the same way as a dataframe object. also, when assigning in this way (`df[cols] = ...`) pandas automatically aligns along the index?

Comment: @Alex my comment with `df.groupby('id')[df.columns[df.columns != 'c']].transform(lambda x: x + 1)` showed you exactly how to do that. Did you ignore it?

Comment: @Alex - Not, you are wrong. You filter `DataFrame`, not `groupby` object

Comment: @Alex - because `df.groupby("id")[cols].transform(fmap)` return `DataFrame` without filtered out columns, so assign back `df[cols] = ...` is necessary here

Comment: @coldspeed: yep, didn't see it. sorry about that! must have not loaded when i was typing a comment response

Comment: @jezrael: df.groupby("id") is a `pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object, so it isn't a dataframe. not sure what the properties of that thing are.. for one it seems you can subset it the same way as a dataframe

Comment: @Alex - I agree with you, but I think `df.groupby("id")[cols].transform(fmap)` return `DataFrame`

Comment: @jezrael: yes, i understand the assignment is necessary but is the order of the rows gauranteed to be the same or does pandas automatically align by index when you do `some_data_frame[cols] = some_other_df[cols]`

Comment: @Alex - Hmmm, without data hard to know, but if same index and columns in `some_data_frame` and `some_other_df` it will works. But if is possible different, better is use `df1 = df.groupby("id")[cols].transform(fmap)` and then `join` or `merge` to another `DataFrame`

Comment: @jezrael: no but i mean specifically when you do the assignment, are the rows aligned properly? (`df[cols] = df.groupby("id")[cols].transform(fmap) `)

Comment: @Alex - yes, pandas do it.