# select all elements in a group that meet a specific condition using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that's grouped by `id`. For each `id` group, I would like to return all the rows where column `a` is greater than the mean of `a` for that group. I tried the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"a": np.arange(10), "b": np.arange(10)[::-1], "c": np.random.choice(a = np.arange(10), size = 10)}, index = pd.Index(data = np.random.choice(a = [1,2,3], size = 10), name = "id"))
df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: x[x.a > x.a.mean()])
```

This raises a ValueError: Duplicated level name: "id", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't get an error when I run this code, using 3.6.2.

Comment: which versions are you on? i'm on pandas: 0.23.0, numpy: 1.14.3 and python 3.6

Comment: I get same error - `python: 3.6.4.final.0, pandas: 0.23.0, numpy: 1.14.3`

Comment: Must be a recent(ish) change, I'm on python 3.6.2, numpy 1.13.1, pandas 20.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for same `Series` as size of original `DataFrame` for better performance like `apply` solution:

```
df = df[df['a'] > df.groupby("id")['a'].transform('mean')]
print (df)
    a  b  c
id         
2   5  4  3
2   6  3  2
1   7  2  3
3   8  1  0
3   9  0  5
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby("id")['a'].transform('mean'))
id
1    4.75
1    4.75
1    4.75
3    3.50
3    3.50
1    4.75
1    4.75
1    4.75
1    4.75
1    4.75
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

---

In your solution need parameter `group_keys=False` for avoid `MultiIndex` with same levels names, because `id` in index name:

```
df = df.groupby("id", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x[x.a > x.a.mean()])
```

If first `reset_index()` get column name `id` and index name `id`, but there are same values:

```
df = df.reset_index().groupby("id").apply(lambda x: x[x.a > x.a.mean()])
print (df)
      id  a  b  c
id               
2  6   2  6  3  3
   7   2  7  2  9
   9   2  9  0  1
3  5   3  5  4  9
   8   3  8  1  8
```

Another test - removing `index name` - `id`:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None)
print (df)
   a  b  c
3  0  9  2
2  1  8  2
1  2  7  6
3  3  6  1
1  4  5  3
2  5  4  9
3  6  3  6
2  7  2  1
1  8  1  0
1  9  0  1

df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x[x.a > x.a.mean()])
print (df)
     a  b  c
1 1  8  1  0
  1  9  0  1
2 2  5  4  9
  2  7  2  1
3 3  6  3  6
```

Comment: ok i see how that works but what's the issue with what i did?

Comment: i see your detail edit but i still don't understand why my method fails

Comment: ahh ok, makes sense now: this only exists because you can group on other things than the index, correct? ie a column or some f(column)

Comment: @Alex - hmmm, I think your solution is perfectly OK, in my opinion it is small bug only if `index` has name. If removing, it works, check last edit.

Comment: i think the `group_keys = False` is the right approach to fixing this, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @Alex - Yes, also removeing duplicated level, but if performance is important `transform` is my choice.

Comment: the issue with groupby transform is it is not well documented (for example see my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558229/applying-a-function-to-a-subset-of-columns-in-pandas-groupby)